# If i enter a value above 16383 in this C program that converts decimal to binary, it doesn't work. Why?

Tags: c, variables, memory, binary

This is a decimal to binary converter, where the user inputs a decimal number and its binary version is outputted. It works fine except when the input number (shown as the variable 'a' in this code) is greater than 16383. I'm not quite sure why. Another curious thing is that when 16383 is used as the input number, the binary output is just a long series of 1's. Not sure if that's a clue to the answer.

Anyways, here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
  clrscr();
  int a,x=1;

  printf("Enter your number in base 10:");
  scanf("%d",&a);//max value:16383 for some reason??

  while(x<=a)
  {
    x=x*2;
  }

  x=x/2;
  printf("\nBinary version:");

  if(x==1)
    printf("1");
  else
  {
    while(x>=1)
    {
      if(a/x==1)
      {
        printf("1");
        a=a-x;
      }
      else
        printf("0");

      x=x/2;
    }
  }

  getch();
}
```

Comment: works for me if I remove the conio.h parts and change `void main` to `int main`: https://ideone.com/KlTpOR

Comment: what is `sizeof(int)` on your machine? use `unsigned long x`

Comment: `conio.h` was used on old DOS compilers. I'll hazard a guess: Mr Baid is from India, where Turbo C++ is still popular with teachers.

Comment: also use `x <<= 1` instead of `x*=2` to better match the intended logic

Comment: @MSalters:: With all due respect, I don't find your survey on "India's-most-popular-compiler-among-teacher", to be accurate with data. So, I would appreciate your effort if you would refrain yourself before making any such enlightening comment. No offence.

Comment: @Abhineet: I don't recall any Turbo C++ question from any other country. I've followed the C++ tag for 7 years, so I should know. Also, I didn't say **most** popular, nor did I say that the popularity of Turbo C++ is unique to India.

Comment: @MSalters: Noooo..., why do I have to lose the argument always :-P I browsed through the net, and yes, it does seem that your comment is true.

Comment: Yup - just from the title, I know 'conio' and 16-bit integers:(

Comment: @MSalters Close, I'm from London but you are quite correct in that I am learning in India. They told me Turbo C++ was the best compiler for C and C++. Would you suggest something else?

Comment: @DrKoch sizeof(int) comes out at 2 bytes but I'm still not sure why that matters? Could you please clear things up for me? Thanks                                       Also, what does 'x <<= 1' mean?

Comment: @SahilBaid: [Chart listing various compiler's support for advanced C++ features](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support). Turbo C++ isn't even *on* that chart, and its successor Embarcadero C++Builder doesn't really look good in it. GCC, MSVC and Clang pretty much got covered between the three of them...

Comment: I would definitely, absolutely advise something else. Whether that's GCC, MSVC++ or Clang does not matter. All are free and all are lightyears better that Turbo C++. I would strongly advise you to reconsider that particular C++ course given that the teacher absolutely does not understand compiler quality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you, by any chance, working on a 16-bit machine (where `sizeof(int)` is `2`)?

Because 16383 is `0x3fff`. One more is `0x4000`, which when doubled here...

```
while(x<=a)
{
    x=x*2;
}
```

...would give `0x8000`, which would wrap into negative values on a 16-bit machine.

(Just in case you are not familiar with `0x...`, that is [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) notation, which makes it easier to see bit patterns.)

---

`int` is a *signed* type, i.e. it can hold negative numbers. On [most modern platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), negatives are those with their most significant bit set. That would be `0x8000-0xffff` for 16bit machines, and `0x80000000-0xffffffff` on 32bit machines.

So, ever-larger positive numbers (`0x7ffe`, `0x7fff`) can suddenly become small *negative* numbers (`0x8000`). If you're using *unsigned* types (i.e. `unsigned int`), you get a similar "wraparound" from "really large" to "zero".

On your machine, 16383 times two is 32766.

But 16384 times two is (thanks to the limited range of numbers that can be represented in 16 bits) actually -2 -- at which point your program breaks.

Comment: Yes, my sizeof(int) is 2. I'm not sure what the rest of your answer means though. Sorry, I'm new to computer science.

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of your integer, they may be 16 bits, making 16383 the largest integer to fit in a signed 16 bit integer, I think.

printf("%i",sizeof(int));

Comment: That would be a 15 bits integer, actually.

Comment: Not really, MSalters; a 16-bits integer includes the sign bit.

Comment: @RoyDictus: I know. But 16383 is **14** bits, plus a sign is 15. C and C++ both require `INT_MAX >= 32767`.